# Existence of ample divisor with smooth image

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper, generically finite morphism between smooth, projective varieties.

Is there an ample divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $f(D)$ is smooth?